# copy one dictionary from a python file and paste it to corresponding json file

Tags: python, json, string, list, dictionary

I have a python file named `abc.py` which have following function.
abc.py:

```py
    def variables(self, output_analysis):
        self.variables_list = [

            {
                'name': 'primary_metric',
                'description': 'The single measure selected',
                'datatype': type(output_analysis['primary_metric']).__name__,
                'value': output_analysis['primary_metric'],
                'scenario': ["abc.json"]
            },

            {
                'name': 'secondary_entity_first',
                'description': f' Which {output_analysis["focus_on_dimension"]} is on 1st rank in terms of {output_analysis["secondary_metric"]} in {output_analysis["current_period"]}.',
                'datatype': type(output_analysis['secondary_entity_first']).__name__,
                'value': output_analysis['secondary_entity_first'],
                'scenario': ["compare_rank_for_focus_on_scenario__000__0_0_0_0_0.json"]
            }
         ]

        variables_dict = {
            'variables': self.variables_list
        }

        return variables_dict
```

I want to copy `self.variables` dictionary to `abc.json` file in the following format:

1) replacing the single quotes to the double quotes

2) replacing the double quotes around all the keys of output_analysis to single quotes

3) putting all the values in double quotes which don't have any quotes around them.

abc.json:

```py
       {

      "truth_table": {
        "business_logic": {
            "department": {
                "name": "default"
            },
            "domain": {
                "name": "default"
            },

            "variables": [
                {
                    "name": "primary_metric",
                    "description": "The single measure selected",
                    "datatype": "type(output_analysis['primary_metric']).__name__",
                    "value": "output_analysis['primary_metric']"
                },

                {
                    "name": "secondary_entity_first",
                    "description": "f'Which {output_analysis['focus_on_dimension']} is on 1st rank in terms of {output_analysis["secondary_metric"]} in {output_analysis["current_period"]}.'",
                    "datatype": "type(output_analysis['secondary_entity_first']).__name__",
                    "value": "output_analysis['secondary_entity_first']"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

As I have multiple files, I want to write a script in python for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dump` method to dump the variables dictionary into the json file.
Simply import json first.

Then you can use this code:

```
with open("jsonFilePath") as jsonfile:
json.dump(variables_dict, jsonfile)
```

That should work...

Comment: That's not working for me because the dictionary output_analysis is getting evaluated while running so